# Swift 2 PhysicsBody not working

Tags: swift2, physics, skphysicsbody

i have a code where i two spaceships floating around the screen however they can't break through the top of the screen and the motto. however they can fly through i sides. i've look at endless about of sites and done some many different types of skphysicsbodys but none of them help. 
code example.

```
class GameScene: SKScene, SKPhysicsContactDelegate {

var player = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "spaceship.png")
var player2 = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "spaceship.png")
var timer = NSTimer()
var tapsValid:Bool?
var playerRight:Bool?
var playerChange:Bool?

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    let sceneBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    sceneBody.friction = 0
    self.physicsBody = sceneBody

    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVector(dx: 0.0, dy: 0.0)


    tapsValid = true
    playerRight = true

    self.scene?.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()

    player.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 1.8 + 280)
    player.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: player.size)
    player.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    player.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    player.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    player.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    player.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    player.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0

    player2.position = CGPointMake(self.size.width / 2, self.size.height / 14)
    player2.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOfSize: player2.size)
    player2.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    player2.physicsBody?.dynamic = false
    player2.physicsBody?.restitution = 1
    player2.physicsBody?.friction = 0
    player.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0
    player.physicsBody?.angularDamping = 0

    self.addChild(player)

    self.addChild(player2)
```

can anyone help me out here. i just want to add physics to the edges of the screen. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You should define your colliderTypes and categories for your nodes. That way you can check to see what hits what

```
enum ColliderType: UInt32 {
    case Spaceship = 0
    case CornerCategory = 1
}

self.physicsBody!.categoryBitMask = ColliderType.CornerCategory.rawValue


player.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask =  ColliderType.CornerCategory.rawValue
player2.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = ColliderType.CornerCategory.rawValue

func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {
if contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask {
        //If it is true. Means that bodyA is the spaceship. Because it's 0
        firstBody = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB
    }else{
        //Either way. firstBody will always be the spaceship
        firstBody = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA
    }

    if firstBody.categoryBitMask == ColliderType. Spaceship.rawValue && secondBody.categoryBitMask == ColliderType.CornerCategory.rawValue{
        //means that Spaceship and wall touches
        print("Spaceship hits wall")

        }
}
```